# Swap two numbers using multiplication and division

Tags: java

```
class Swap{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 5;
        int b = 0;
        a = a*b;
        b = a/b;
        a = a/b;
    }
}
```

This will generate an ArithmeticException. My question is that how to solve this problem using try and catch blocks.

Comment: You're trying to divide by 0, which is nonsensical. I think you need to rework your algorithm. Catching that error won't do any good.

Comment: Just change `b` to a non zero value and your code should work.  By the way, this probably is not a good way to swap two numbers.

Comment: You need to solve it by applying mathematical basics such as: division by zero is not allowed. Exception is not a solution for your problem. You use an exception when you know that "something might go wrong", not to protect yourself from obviously bad code. The way you protect yourself from division by zero is checking if (b!=0) but as you declared it as such yourself, it would be nonsens.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this, which will handle your zero exception case of division

In your calling function do like this

```
if (x==0 || y == 0){
    swap(x+1,y+1,1); // Increment 1 so that it won't through exception
}
else{
swap(x,y,0);
}
```

Now create a swap function

```
void swap(int x, int y, bool isSomeOneZero){
x = x * y; // x now becomes 50
y = x / y; // y becomes 10
x = x / y; // x becomes 5
if (isSomeOneZero){
    x = x - 1; // Decrement value by 1 which is incremented previously
    y = y - 1 ;
}
printf("After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d", x, y);

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, swapping two numbers with using multiplication and division logic is not a good approach. There are far better and straightforward algorithms available to do that.

However, if you must do it using your method, maybe due to an exercise or homework assignment, you can increment the number by 1 if it is zero, then perform your logic and finally decrement the other number, since it is swapped, by 1. See the following example:

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 0;
    boolean aplus = false;
    boolean bplus = false;
    if (a == 0) {
        a++;
        aplus = true;
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        b++;
        bplus = true;
    }
    a = a*b;
    b = a/b;
    a = a/b;

    if(aplus)b--;
    if(bplus)a--;
```

Answer (score 0):

//Java Program for swapping two numbers using two variables with '* 'and '/' Operators

```
class MulDivSwapping
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         try
         {
             int a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
             int b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
             System.out.println("Before swapping 'a' and  'b' values are: \n a="+a+"\n b=" +b);     
             if(a==0)
             {
                 a=b;
                 b=0;
             }
             else if(b==0)
             {
                 b=a;
                 a=0;
             }
             else           
             {
                a=a*b;  
                b=a/b;
                a=a/b;
             }
             System.out.println("After swapping 'a' and  'b' values are: \n a="+a+"\n b="+b);   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println("please Enter the two integer values for 'a' and 'b' variables @ Runtime...!");
        }       
    }
 }
```